# How to add player box with name and image?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have game with four players.
How can I add four player boxes where each box contains text (players name) and image (avatar)?

The goal is to create box, add image and text label into and then set position of that box in the game.

I searched in phaser examples but without luck.

Thank you

Comment: nobody doesn't have information?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?